# How to change android app icon background color in xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android

Variations of this question have been asked over the years but I have not found anything current, up-to-date, and step-by-step.  The closest thing I have found is this but it is hard to follow and not completely accurate.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/696540/background-color-for-launcher-icons.html

For instance, it refers to Visual Studio 2017 documentation on how to change the app icon that just does not work even in the Visual Studio 2022.  Really, after so many years we have no easy way of setting the app icon?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows#specify-the-application-icon

I my case I was really just trying to change the background color, which was showing up correctly under iOS but under Android was just white.  So what is the best way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

So the current site for creating all your iOS and Android icons is here:

https://icon.kitchen/

You upload your image with a transparent background and then select your background color.  It gives you a preview of what your icon will look like and you tap Download to get a zip file containing all the icons you need with the proper folder structure.

In the case of Android you copy the mipmap* folders into your res or Resource folder in the Droid project folder.

There is one adjustment that you will have to make to the two files in the mipmap-anydpi-v26 folder.  They come named "ic_launcher" but for some buggy reason they need to be named "icon".

After changing their name we encounter the next critical step due to the bug in the "Droid project Properties/Android Manifest/Application icon".  You should be able to set your icon here but it does not work!  Instead you must modify AndroidManifest.xml by hand to add the android:icon as follows:

```
<application android:label="γDog" android:theme="@style/MyTheme" android:icon="@mipmap/icon">
```

If you ever change the properties again you will need to make this change again because it will revert back and cause an error in your compilation.

One caveat is that on some Android platforms the background color is evidently not used and is instead left transparent.